# Create TimeStamp with fixed Time Part

Tags: oracle, timestamp, sysdate

What's the best way to get a timestamp that consists of the actual date but a fixed time part in oracle.

e.g.Today and always 09:00:00

`2020-10-20 09:00:00`

in MSSQL I would use `FORMAT(GETDATE(),'yyyy-MM-dd 09:00:00')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want a `date` rather than a `varchar2`, I'd use

```
trunc(sysdate) + interval '9' hour
```

`trunc(sysdate)` returns today at midnight and then `interval '9' hour` adds 9 hours to give you 9am.  You can also add fractions of a day to a `date` so you could say

```
trunc(sysdate) + 9/24
```

I tend to find the `interval` notation more self-explanatory particularly if you're coming from a non-Oracle background.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

SQL> `alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY-MM-DD';`

```
Session altered.
```

SQL> `set head off`

SQL> `select sysdate||' 09:00:00' from dual;`

```
2020-10-19 09:00:00
```

Hope this is what you were looking for :)

Comment: This returns a **string** - I would suggest `TRUNC(SYSDATE) + 9/24` in order to get a `DATE` value